# libgdx - как сделать кнопку с текстом?

Tags: libgdx

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать кнопку в `libgdx`? Без всяких скинов. Есть шрифт (.png + .ftn). Я делаю `Rectangle` и хочу поместить в него текст. Шрифт загружен в `BitmapFont`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, со скинами libgdx полная засада. Скинов с русскими буквами я не нашёл.
Рисовать их вручную очень хлопотно. Вот 3 варианта, какие я реально использовал:

1. Вместо кнопки берём Image из scene 2D. К Image можно прикрутить слушатель clickListener. Текст тоже 2 варианта: либо он уже в картинке, либо выводим поверх кнопки через SpriteBatch, используя BitmapFont.
2. Берём всё-таки Button или TextButton (но текст не задаём). Преимущество перед Image - хоть какая-то анимация нажатия. Для нужного текста создаём glyphLayout. Благодаря этому знаем ширину и высоту текста. Кнопку делаем чуть выше и чуть шире. И также выводим текст на кнопку через bitmapfont.draw.

В обоих случаях всё-таки придётся прикрутить дефолтный англоязычный скин.

Если хотите вообще без скинов, это значит вообще без виджетов. Тогда

3. В качестве кнопки берём Texture. Ну или если хотите кнопку с анимацией, то TextureRegion. Создаём rectangle с размерами, аналогичными нашей texture. У класса Rectangle есть метод contains. Это для слушателя кликов. Создаёте touchPosition класса Vector3 для координат нажатия. Нажатия слушаем в теле render:
   if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
       touchPosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
       if (rectangle.contains(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y){
           ... тут всё что после нажатия на кнопку
       }
   }
   Текст выводим всё также с помощью bitmapfont.draw.