# Как создать кнопку в libgdx?

Tags: android, button, libgdx

Здравствуйте) Пытаюсь в классе, наследуемом от `Stage`, создать и нарисовать Button. Создаю пустую кнопку `Button`, добавляю её через `addActor`. Но при прорисовке приложение на `Android` вылетает. К сожалению, проверить на компьютере не могу. Из всех примеров создания кнопки везде добавлялся скин к ней. Могу я просто добавить прямоугольную серую кнопку с текстом и если могу, то как?

Comment: Да, в классе, наследуемом от Screen, в методе render я вызываю draw из класса, наследуемом от Stage

Answer (score 0):

По поводу рисования кнопок [был вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601657/libgdx-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC/603085#603085). 
насчёт вылета: не очень понятно "Пытаюсь в классе, наследуемом от Stage, создать и нарисовать Button". Обычно рисуют в классе, наследуемом от Screen (а точнее имплементируемом), а от Stage просто создаётся экземпляр и в него добавляются актёры.